# Why does my performSegueWithIdentifier end up without a back button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue, uisplitviewcontroller

For some reason when I do performSegueWithIdentifier from an add view, the back button is missing from the iPhone simulator.

This is a "Master-Detail Application" template, with the add button going to a new UIView.
(The whole demo is on [github](https://github.com/hackzilla/SegueProblem))

**Programmically clicked**
[image: Programmically clicked]

**User clicked**
[image: User clicked]

My add view calls the following code on the table controller:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
//[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];

NSIndexPath* selectedCellIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:selectedCellIndexPath animated:false scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"showDetail" sender:[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedCellIndexPath]];
```

However running this code directly from the table view works without issue.

So I'm at a loss as to why the back button doesn't show up on the iPhone. (iPad version seems to work perfectly).

Comment: It seems like the segue does not perform push operation. Please check the segue action in connection inspector.

Comment: I cloned your repo and checked out your code. To be straight, it all looks very confusing to me. I tried to make changes but gave up after sometime. I think 'New Detail View' with the 'Create' button should be behind a separate Navigation controller. You won't need to do things like `setReturnController` and `popViewController` in that case. I have done a similar Segue setup in my [sample](https://github.com/palewar/Swift-Samples) and have detailed my approach on my [blog](http://swiftwala.com/multiple-detail-views/). It's done in Swift but I am sure you will understand it easily.

Comment: insane-36 spot on. Since changing it works perfectly.

Comment: turns out it breaks the iPad version. Seems I need "show" for iPhone and "show detail" for the iPad to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried a few different strategies to solving my issue.

The closest I've found is to display the add as a modal, segue to detail, unwind segue.

It still suffers a little on iPad version, (the add button disappears on add), but works better than my original code.

[Solution on Github](https://github.com/hackzilla/SegueProblem/tree/new-detail-unwind)

If anyone has a better solution, then I'm happy to change the accepted answer.